# Entity Framework (EF) modifying an instance that is already in the context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

im working on school project that contains desktop(windows forms) and windows phone application. The error is in Api Controller, Edit action.

This is the WebApi Call:

```
 HttpResponseMessage responseProizvodi;
            if (proizvod.ProizvodID == 0)
                responseProizvodi = proizvodiService.PostResponse(proizvod);
            else responseProizvodi = proizvodiService.PutResponse(proizvod.ProizvodID,proizvod);
```

My methods in WebApiHelper class:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostResponse(Object o)
    {
        return client.PostAsJsonAsync(route, o).Result;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage PutResponse(int id, Object o)
    {
        return client.PutAsJsonAsync(route + "/" + id, o).Result;
    }
```

and ApiController which is generated using Entity Framework:

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutProizvodi(int id, Proizvodi proizvodi)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != proizvodi.ProizvodID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(proizvodi).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProizvodiExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

at this line:

```
 db.Entry(proizvodi).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

i got this error:

> Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'WebApi.Models.Proizvodi' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I read the questions/answers on a similar topic, but I didn't find the answer.

One of them say that we have to detach the local version and set to modify the entity we are modifying.

A way to do it is to navigate inside the local of the DbSet to see if this one is there. If the entity is present, than you detach.

```
 var local = yourDbContext.Set<YourModel>()
                         .Local
                         .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == yourModel.Id);
if (local != null)
{
  yourDbContext.Entry(local).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
yourDbContext.Entry(applicationModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

In my case, local is null, and EntityState is Deatached, but still i have the same error. Any help ?

EDIT:
My db is here:

```
 public class ProizvodiController : ApiController
{
    private eProdajaEntities db = new eProdajaEntities();
    //actions
 }
```

Comment: It is unclear where you initialize or dispose of `db`. However, for a web application it is bad practice to keep a DbContext open across multiple HTTP calls. The moment multiple clients access the context, it will be in a confused and chaotic state. Best practice is to create and dispose of your DbContext within the body of your action method.

Comment: Db is instiantiated as private member of Controller class:
  public class ProizvodiController : ApiController
    {
        private eProdajaEntities db = new eProdajaEntities();
//action
//action
//....
    }

Comment: Accepting an entire domain object and then saving it is a glaring security flaw. You should refine what properties you expect to be edited and then update the domain object yourself. Using that approach you would not run into this error in the first place.

Comment: Probably your Dbcontext is not disposed properly.

Comment: I'd examine what is being sent back to the server, you may have a nav property that is being serialized or you're not handling the ID properly in the first place.  Also when you are accessing your context, are you doing so in a using statement?  If not, and if you are not explicitly disposing, this will likely cause an error like you describe here.

Comment: You have to first get the entity from your context before attaching it for changes. There's no way EF can know that your proizvodi is part of the context. What I see is happening is that since Ef doesn't know about your proizvodi, it will create a new one, which is causing the "same primary key value" error.

Answer (score 0):

The `Proizvodi` object being passed to your `PutProizvodi` method is not tracked by EF (i.e. it doesn't know where it came from because it wasn't involved in the creation of the entity instance; that instance was created by the Web.API model binder which has no idea about your database or EF) which is probably why it's throwing the error.

Just because the type `Proizvodi` is an entity type, doesn't mean it's automatically tracked by EF; only objects retrieved by EF will be tracked.

You would need to first obtain an instance of the right `Proizvodi` object by first looking it up via EF using the `id` you are passing to your `PutProizvodi` method, rather than using the `Proizvodi` instance that the model binder is passing in.

You *could* use a `Proizvodi` object to pass into your `PutProizvodi` method, but it's more typically to create a model with similar properties that you then map to your entity instance as required. This allows you to control what properties of your entity objects are passed in and out of your application.

Something like this:-

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutProizvodi(int id, ProizvodiModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // lookup the entity using the id that was passed in    

    var proizvodi = db.Set<Proizvodi>().Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    // if no entity was found with that id, return

    if (proizvodi == null) {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // make the changes to your entity

    proizvodi.SomeProperty = model.SomeProperty;
    // etc

    // then save the changes

    db.SaveChanges();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}

public class ProizvodiModel
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is some property? could you please show me with an exmaple?

Comment: @Thunfische "SomeProperty" is just an example property name on an entity class; In the example above, the "Proizvodi" entity has a property called "SomeProperty", which EF would map to a column in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the problem is in my case. In short, I did the following:

1.

```
WebAPIHelper proizvodiService = new WebAPIHelper("http://localhost:62312/", "api/Proizvodi");
```

1.1

```
private Proizvodi proizvod { get; set; }
```

2.

```
 HttpResponseMessage responseProizvodi=proizvodiService.GetResponse(ProizvodID);
```

3.

```
      Proizvodi p = responseProizvodi.Content.ReadAsAsync<Proizvodi().Result;
      proizvod = p; 
// do some edit on "proizvod" and put to database
      HttpResponseMessage responseProizvod = proizvodiService.PutResponse(proizvod.ProizvodID,proizvod);
```

Whats the point, the same object that i get from database (object "proizvod" which is private property in this class), i send back to database, and thats occur error.

object "p" point to object in database, then object "proizvod" point to the same object, same address, i do some edit, everything put to object "proizvod" and send to PutResponse method.

```
proizvod = new Proizvodi();
```

is missing...now everythig work's fine. I hope that I realized what is the problem. I would love if someone would technically and precisely explained what happened. I am a beginner and trying to figure out how things work, thank you.